# Auto Log Off when opening specific folder (Homework)

Tags: c#

The code below logs off the PC. But what I want is that when I click on a specific folder, for example: `E:\Picture`, Windows should log off.

I don't know how to put such condition in the code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Code for logging of:**

```
using (Process proc = new Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "shutdown.exe");
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l";
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.Start();
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open a folder"? If you are trying to make some securing tool, you'd better use another approach.

Comment: The code has nothing to do with what you ask. Your problem isn't how to execute `shutdown.exe` (especially since there *are* APIs for this) but detecting that Windows Explorer "opened" a folder. Which you can't do without implementing some sort of Shell extension. In any case, such an operation would be worse than pointless - it would be considered malicious

Comment: what I meant to say is that "Click on the folder" the program should log off after detecting the path with is not for access...!!

Comment: Is your question _"How to detect that a user tries to open a certain directory?"_? Can you then define "open"? And no, you don't want to roll your own security like this. You really, really don't.

Comment: Yes it is as you said...!! I meant to say click...!! @CodeCaster

Comment: So "open" means "click"? What if the user navigates to the directory using the keyboard? Or the command prompt? Or an OpenFileDialog? Or the native `OpenFile()` Win32 call? In what context does your application run and in which sessions do you want to detect the access to the given directory/ies? Again, you really, **really** don't want to do this yourself, and certainly not from user-level application code. Just use NTFS permissions.

Comment: This is homework? Please add this in the question.

Comment: Yes it is...!! @RalfdeKleine

Comment: Rephrase the question or this question will be closed. You want to find out how to detect when a user opens a specific folder using explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, here some starting points

1. Create a local hook on explorer.exe
2. Find out if you can use WinAPI to find process information on the explorer
3. ...
4. execute shutdown.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx